# Windows service to read from database and invoke applications based on dates

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf, windows-services

I am developing a data optimization project. It has a client side web app to receive tasks from users. Let's say the tasks are some heavy calculations that cannot be done easily by normal systems. The program takes a long while for big amount of data to be calculated. So what I am trying to do is receive calculation orders from my web application and have a windows service on my server side to listen for new tasks to be done.

I would like my service to be listening to the data that is being inserted into my Tasks table and run the calculator based on the time of those dates. I will of course would have to deal with some multi-threading. And maybe if the program is busy, the other processes would have to wait.

I also don't mind having a small GUI for my application to see which orders are now being processed and whether my service is busy or idle.

I first thought about adding SQL Server jobs in my data base to query the table frequently and run the application based on the dates. But that does not look like a nice solution to me. What I want is a nimble ready-to-serve service who becomes aware when we have new data in the database and decides what to do.

I don't insist on Windows Services particularly here. So any good idea is welcome.

Comment: This sounds like a classic use case for message queueing to me, rather than one for a relational DB...

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in Powershell.
What I have:

- A "queue" table where requests gather
- Requests come in by clients calling a procedure
- A "queue history" table - request already "treated" go from "queue" to "queue_history" (delete trigger)
- A powershell loop reading queue table
- Requests from queue are started independently via `start-job` command, those are actually separate Powershell instances (my tasks are mostly some external exe calls, but I think could be usefull for stored procedure calls also).
- The powershell loop also report his "heartbeat" to a table.
- Also watches a table and file existance for STOP flag so I can stop it.